# Using Snowflake ODBC Driver with MS Access

Tags: ms-access, odbc, linked-tables

I am trying to access my tables in Snowflake using MS Access. I am able to make the connection to make a connection between them and see the list of all my tables but the I am getting all my tables (from all Databases and Schema) even if I have specifically mentioned the Database and Schema to be accessed when creating the Data Source Network(DSN).

And when I try to open a table i get the message: "Cannot define field more than once."

The table which I am accessing has a copy under different database. But, the table name and schema name is same.
ex:
DATABASE_A.SCHEMA.TABLE1
DATABASE_B.SCHEMA.TABLE1

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that if you have two Snowflake databases with the same table name you experience this problem.  I have been beating my head against a wall and your question gave me the clue.  I was able to delete my other database in Snowflake and the error that you described disappeared.

I have come across another problem though but that will be for another SO question.